# how to get unique id and profile info in social auth in integration for facebook

Tags: android, integration, socialauth

i have implement social auth for integration of facebook now i want to get user profile info and unique id .I have get access token but unable to get user profile info .I have implement it by following
    public class SignUp extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText email_mEditText, password_mEditText;

```
SocialAuthAdapter socialAuthAdapter;
private RelativeLayout facebook_layout, twitter_layout, googleplus_layout, linkdin_layout;
private Button signIn_mButton;
String email_mString, password_mString;
private ImageView backIcon_mImageView, logoIcon_mImageView;
private TextView forgotpassword_mTextView;
 String emailid_mString ;
 EditText emailid_mEt;
 Button submit_mbtn;
 Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    signIn_mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin_button);
    email_mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_editText);
    password_mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_editText);
    backIcon_mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backicon_imageView);
    logoIcon_mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoicon_imageView);

    facebook_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.facebook_layout);
    twitter_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.twitter_layout);
    googleplus_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.google_layout);
    linkdin_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linkdin_layout);
    facebook_layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    twitter_layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    googleplus_layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    linkdin_layout.setOnClickListener(this);

    socialAuthAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    signIn_mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    backIcon_mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    logoIcon_mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    forgotpassword_mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword_textView);
    forgotpassword_mTextView.setPaintFlags(forgotpassword_mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    forgotpassword_mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.signin_button:

        email_mString = email_mEditText.getText().toString();
        password_mString = password_mEditText.getText().toString();
        if ((email_mString.isEmpty()) && (password_mString.isEmpty())) {
            email_mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     email_mEditText.setError("Value required");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     email_mEditText.setError(null);
                }
            });


        } else if ((email_mString.isEmpty())) {
            email_mEditText.setError("Please Enter the Email ");

        } else if ((password_mString.isEmpty())) {
             password_mEditText.setError("Please Enter the Password ");
        } else {

            Log.d("u r", "ur in else part");
            new Thread(null, threadEventListing, "").start();

        }
        break;
    case R.id.backicon_imageView:
        Intent signInIntent = new Intent(SignUp.this, SignIn.class);
        startActivity(signInIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.logoicon_imageView:
        Intent signIntent = new Intent(SignUp.this, SignIn.class);
        startActivity(signIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.forgotpassword_textView:

        Log.d("hello", "u clicked FOrgot textview");
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.forgot_password);
        emailid_mEt=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etforgotpassword);
        submit_mbtn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
        submit_mbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                emailid_mString = emailid_mEt.getText().toString();
                new Thread(null,threadForgotPassword,"").start();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

        break;
    case R.id.facebook_layout:

        socialAuthAdapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
        socialAuthAdapter.signOut(this, Provider.FACEBOOK.toString());

        break;

    case R.id.twitter_layout:

        socialAuthAdapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.TWITTER);
        socialAuthAdapter.signOut(this, Provider.TWITTER.toString());

        break;

    case R.id.google_layout:
        socialAuthAdapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.GOOGLEPLUS);
        socialAuthAdapter.signOut(this, Provider.GOOGLEPLUS.toString());

        break;

    case R.id.linkdin_layout:
        socialAuthAdapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.LINKEDIN);
        socialAuthAdapter.signOut(this, Provider.LINKEDIN.toString());
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent signInIntent = new Intent(SignUp.this, SignIn.class);
    startActivity(signInIntent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    finish();
}

private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.d("tag", "In on comppleter");

        String token = socialAuthAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey();
        Log.d("Token", token);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_location"));

        authButton.setFragment(this);
        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (state.isOpened()) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            makeMeRequest(session);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {

        // Make an API call to get user data and define a
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            /*
             * @Override public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response
             * response) { // If the response is successful if (session ==
             * Session.getActiveSession()) { if (user != null) { // Set the
             * id for the ProfilePictureView // view that in turn displays
             * the profile picture. Log.e("user",user.toString()); } } if
             * (response.getError() != null) { // Handle errors, will do so
             * later. } }
             */

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("FB Return", user.toString());
                Log.e("FullName", user.getName());
                Log.e("Id", user.getId());
                Log.e("username", "" + user.getUsername());
                Log.e("Fname", user.getFirstName());
                Log.e("Fname", user.getLastName());
                Log.e("gender", user.asMap().get("gender").toString());

                String gender = user.asMap().get("gender").toString();
                String email = (String) user.asMap().get("email") + "";
                Log.e("email", email);
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {

            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: i know how to store and get session ..i m talking about how to get user profile info and unique id in integration of fb when using #SocialAuth lib in android

Comment: follow the method 

public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response){

============

}

Comment: now plz check how i have implement that @Avishek Das

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Social Auth, so you can try this :

```
private final class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener {

@Override
public void onExecute(Profile t) {

  Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
  Profile profileMap = t;
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Validate ID = " + profileMap.getValidatedId());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "First Name  = " + profileMap.getFirstName());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Last Name  = " + profileMap.getLastName());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Email  = " + profileMap.getEmail());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Gender  = " + profileMap.getGender());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Country  = " + profileMap.getCountry());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Language  = " + profileMap.getLanguage());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Location  = " + profileMap.getLocation());
  Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Profile Image URL = " + profileMap.getProfileImageURL()); }
```

Comment: I tried that ..but that dint work for me ..@gautam joshi

Comment: i wanna ask when i implement that method ..in onExecute it have 2 parameter how i handle this   public void onExcute(String srt,Object obj){